# Unable to generate a temporary class - Cryptographic failure while signing assembly

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, sign, sgen

I have a signed class library that I want to create assemblies for via the sgen tool. However, I get an error when I try to run the following command:

> $ sgen.exe /a:testsign.dll /force /compiler:/keyfile:..\..\testsign.pfx /verbose /n
>   Error: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS1548: Cryptographic
>   failure while signing assembly '[...path...]\TestSign.XmlSerializers.dll'
>   -- 'Error signing assembly -
>   - The parameter is incorrect. '
>
> If you would like more help, please type "sgen /?".

I checked the error on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t21abc4c%28VS.80%29.aspx) which states that

> CS1548 occurs when assembly signing fails. This is usually due to an
>   invalid key file name, an invalid key file path, or a corrupt key
>   file.

However, I just created the key, the path is correct and to my knowledge Visual Studio 2010 does not create corrupt keys.

This issue is fairly simple to reproduce.

1. Using the code [pasted here](http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/G1LbQutp60Kr6AMniw96bA) create a new class library.
2. Create two classes, one `class TestSigning` and one `class Model`
3. go to Project properties > Signing and check the "Sign this assembly"
4. create a new Strong name key file
5. open up Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)
6. locate the dll and run `sgen /a:<dllname> [... as above ...]`

My guess is something with the public key for the keyfile.. But I cannot find any sources as to how I inform `sgen` of what password I have used to protect my key file.

I am not sure how to proceed. the other threads I have looked at here on SO have the same error "header" `unable to generate temporary class` but different error details, for which none has the `Cryptographic failure` (that I have found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the instructions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766655/xml-serialization-assembly-for-non-web-projects-solved) solved this issue. Although it wasn't done manually with the `sgen` tool, it was done via Visual Studio.

That is, the above example is changed to:

1. as before
2. as before
3. as before
4. as before
5. Go to the Build tab
6. Set the *Generate serialization assembly* to **On**
7. Right click the project and select *Unload project*
8. Right click the project and select *edit nnn.csproj**
9. Paste the following snippet somewhere

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <SGenUseProxyTypes>false</SGenUseProxyTypes>
       <SGenPlatformTarget>$(Platform)</SGenPlatformTarget>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
10. Reload and build the project.

Comment: Not Working:) Same problem persisting @Default

Comment: it worked 3 years ago when I posted this answer. If you have an issue, may I suggest to post a new question? (if you want you can link to this question and explain why it didn't help you so that it is not closed as a duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was able to build projects without any hiccups. 
It was rather weird when another simple project could not be build/published and threw this error instead.

I was able to build this after I ran Visual Studio as **Administrator**.

Reference: [Gordon's 3log](http://31og.com/post/cryptographic-failure-while-signing-assembly)